# jQuery event for placeholder change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I was wondering if there is a jQuery event, or is there an easy way to simulate one, that is triggered when an HTML5 placeholder hides / shows.

I tried things with a *keyup* event but I need to keep track of the field "state" to check whether or not the placeholder may have changed. Anything simpler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there's no "placeholder" event.

However, you can catch `focus`, `blur` & `key*` events and check `.val()` for any content.

Unfortunately each browser implements the placeholder text differently though. For instance:

- IE10 & Chrome shows placeholder text as long as there isn't any content in the field (even after focusing, as soon as you clear the field the placeholder text returns).
- Safari only shows the placeholder while the [empty] control doesn't have `focus`.
- FF on the other hand only shows it on the initial focus (while the control's empty). Then, once you gain focus and type something it's gone until you `blur` the control with no content.